# Is there a diff tool that allows copy-paste

Tags: diff, copy-paste

Is there a diff tool that allows you to paste two segments of text and get a diff?  I can't use an online tool because I'm dealing with proprietary data, and I haven't found a tool that provides that feature.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).  It'll do that.

Steps:

1. Download and install winmerge
2. Open WinMerge & Create new `<CTRL+N>`
3. Paste into left & right, then refresh `<F5>`

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't see this feature mentioned on it's website, but it does in fact allow pasting text directly.

Comment: To do it: 1) press ctrl+N. 2) paste left and right texts. 3) press F5 or refresh button. If you change the texts you must press refresh button again.

Comment: @Fernando thanks for pointing out the *Refresh* thing, it isn't obvious that you have to click that button to get it going

Comment: It seems that you still have to save the file first, before comparing. So it's not real copy & paste ...

Comment: @testing, as mentioned by Fernando in the comments above, hit "Refresh" after you paste and you're golden.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: Thanks for the tip. This seems to work. But the comparing performance is ...

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone comes here looking for a tool for Macs that can do this, it seems that there are two tools that can do just this.

- [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), the Mac version is currently in beta.
- [Kaleidoscope app](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/)

  1. Copy first text
  2. *File -> New from Clipboard*
  3. Copy second text
  4. *Edit -> Paste to comparison*

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to change the texts once they've been pasted.

There is also a similar (closed) question (the question itself was for a Mac tool, but at least one answer has an alternative diff tool for Windows):

[Diff tool for Mac without saving text to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817242/diff-tool-for-mac-without-saving-text-to-files)

Answer (score 5):

For those who use [Atom](https://atom.io/), there’s the [split-diff](https://atom.io/packages/split-diff) package.

Answer (score 5):

KDiff3 can do that too. On startup just Cancel the open dialog and than copy&paste snippets into the two panes. It immediately (re)computes their diff.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ makes it really easy to do that: paste first text, open new tab, paste second text then Plugin > Compare > Compare.

Make sure you have the compare plugin installed.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817384/965176

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for - [Line Diff](http://linediff.com/) - it's a online tool that takes as input two snippets of code/text, diff them and then render a nice github like html page (permanent or temporary stored) that you can then share with coworkers.

Answer (score 1):

I used [BBEdit](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bbedit/id404009241) (Mac OS X):

- paste your snippets into 2 separate new documents (without saving)
- go to search → find differences
- using the clock icon, pick your new documents

The app has a subscription model, but this doesn't seem to be a premium feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can try online tools
it's good

https://www.diffchecker.com/

Or you can try KDIFF3 its also a good tool 
http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

also you can try [online diff tool](http://wtools.io/check/diff-compare-merge) , maybe it's useful to you.

Comment: online diff tools are not recommended as sites can log your data and use it for their data mining.